# How to define a C++ preprocessor variable in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a C++ preprocessor written like this:

```
  #ifdef cpp_variable
   //x+y;
  #endif
```

How can I define this in *Makefile*?

Answer (score 58):

This is compiler specific.

[GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-2.95.3/gcc_2.html) uses `-Dcpp_variable=VALUE`  or just `-Dcpp_variable`

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8(v=VS.71).aspx)'s compilers use `/D`

Answer (score 37):

Search your compiler documentation to find how to do that.

For example, for `g++`, the syntax is:

```
g++ -Dcpp_variable <other stuff>
```

Which corresponds to adding

```
CPPFLAGS += -Dcpp_variable
```

in your makefile.

Comment: Technically, because you can do it from the commandline, it can be done from the makefile -- just put the relevant command in the makefile. (pedantry aside, this comment may not have actually been correct when this answer was written)

Answer (score 12):

Add to Makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS = -Dcpp_variable
```

Answer (score 5):

The syntax is compiler-specific. For GCC, use the [`-D`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-D-1) option like so: `-Dcpp_variable`.

Answer (score 4):

Take a variable in Makefile and whatever you need to define in it just add -DXXX. Where XXX in you case is cpp_variable.

For example

COMPILE_OPTS = -DXXX

g++ -c $(COMPILE_OPTS) $<

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do the below in a C/C++ file,

```cpp
#define VARIABLE_NAME 2
```

then, in the [Makefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Makefile), use the below lines:

```
CDEFS += -DVARIABLE_NAME = 2
```

Comment: Doesn't it depend on what compiler? Or is it a convention?

Comment: Is this a bogus answer? Does it actually work? Aren't spaces around equal signs significant?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I think its a very low quality answer.