# makefile: passing preprocessor through makefile to g++

Tags: makefile

I saw previous SO posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213800/how-to-define-c-preprocessor-variable-in-makefile), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826029/passing-additional-variables-from-command-line-to-make) etc. I want to pass a preprocessor directive at compile time. With scons, I could do:

```
num_times = ARGUMENTS.get('c', 1)
env.Append(CCFLAGS = '-DNUM_TIMES=%d' % int(num_times))
```

I hope, it should also be possible using make. I want to issue

```
make c=4
```

or something like that. Can someone suggest a method. I am compiling a folder, which has subfolders with their own makefiles. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach is to do:

```
CFLAGS += -DNUM_TIMES=$(c)
export CFLAGS

all:
    $(MAKE) -C your_subfolder
```

call with `make c=2`, and not to touch `CFLAGS` in the sub-folder makefiles.

Another is to have a `Makefile` part in your root folder with all the common settings that you `include` in your subdirectory makefiles (with `include`). (`$(MAKE)` ensures that the command line arguments you gave to `make` will also be passed to sub-makes.)

Comment: Thanks. Is it OK, if the sub-makefiles do: CFLAGS += $(CXXFLAGS)

Comment: Just make sure you don't do the same thing in the main makefile and in the subfile and at the same time export in the main - you'll get things doubled up in your variables, which could be problematic. The best is (probably) not to `export` but have a common make snippet that you include everywhere with the settings you want.